# Program run with Task Scheduler doesn't work properly (create file)

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I have a Ruby program compiled as an .exe. It checks a website for some data, and stores it in a text file before printing a success message and exiting. When I run the program by double-clicking, it runs and generates the file. When I run it through Task Scheduler, however, (whether scheduled or simply by clicking Run), it outputs the success message but no file is generated.

- I'm using an administrator account and have checked the box to run with the highest privileges.
- I've gone into the Properties of the program and set it to always run with elevated privileges.
- The file is being created in a non-shared directory on my account

What possible reason could there be for this not working?

Comment: try specifying a Start In path on the action, and see if that helps. have you ever logged in as the user running the job?

Comment: That stops it from running at all...nothing launches, not even taskeng.exe. I solved it by modifying my program to use an absolute path to the saved data location but I'd still rather get this working so it can be used on multiple machines without modification.